# segmentation fault (core dumped) while trying to allocate memory using (char**)malloc()

Tags: c

I'm new to C and currently learning how to dynamically allocate memory. Currently, I'm trying to create a dynamically allocated character array, where the memory for each individual string is also dynamically allocated. Each string is retrieved from a line in a txt file (numIngredients = number of lines | MAX_ING = maximimum number of characters per line/ingredient).

```
char** readIngredients(int numIngredients){
  FILE *in;
  in = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  char** ingredients;
  ingredients = (char**)malloc(numIngredients*sizeof(char));
  for(int i=0; i<numIngredients; i++){
    ingredients[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_ING*sizeof(char));
  }

  for(int i=0; i<numIngredients; i++){
    fscanf(in, "%s", ingredients[i]);
  }

  fclose(in);
  return ingredients;
}
```

the segmentation fault seems to happen right when I declare ingredients... what am i doing wrong

Comment: Maybe this is an assignment for how to use malloc() but I would not malloc() here.  And fscanf() is easy but not used in robust code any more since you cant supply the length. If you're on Windows use fscanf_s()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to allocate memory in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662649/ways-to-allocate-memory-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating enough memory for an array of pointers:

```
ingredients = (char**)malloc(numIngredients*sizeof(char));
```

Instead, you allocate space for `numIngredients` elements of size `sizeof(char)`.  This causes you to overrun allocated memory triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Multiply by the size of a `char *` instead, so:

```
ingredients = malloc(numIngredients*sizeof(char *));
```

Or even better:

```
ingredients = malloc(numIngredients*sizeof(*ingredients));
```

As it doesn't depend on the type of `ingredients`.